# Ошибка импорта модуля random Python 3.10.2

Tags: python-3.x

Изучаю Python - возникла непонятная ситуация
Python 3.10.2 При попытке импортировать модуль random IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.1 выдаёт ошибку: No module named 'random'.
Файл не называется random.py и рядом подобных файлов нет.
Проблема появилась после переустановки Windows и установки чуть более нового Питона, до этого стоял 3.10 и всё работало нормально.
Полагаю, что стабильность последнего Питона хромает, но может что-то ещё?

```
import random


seconds = random.randint(1, 20)

for second in range(-seconds + 1, 1):
    neutralize = int(input('Хотите ли обезвредить бомбу сейчас? Да - 1, нет - 0: '))
    if neutralize == 1:
        print(f'Бомба обезврежена за {-second + 1} секунд(-ы, -у) до взрыва!')
        print(f'Вы получаете {seconds + second} очк(-ов, -о, -а )!')
        break
    elif second == 0:
        print('Бомба взорвалась!!!')
    else:
        print('Продолжаем')
```

Comment: А вы случайно не используете виртуальное окружение? Может, его нужно пересоздать?

Comment: Нет, не использую, так и не понял, в чём проблема, ну да ладно, видимо что-то или с python 3.10.2 или с IJ